# Android: How to unit test Observable concatMap compose with mockK

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java2, mockk

I need to unit test an Observable with concatMap and then compose.

I'am using RxJava and mockk library.

I've been trying to use two separetes `every` statements to mock the results.
But when i call first

```
every {
    remoteLocalInteractor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()
        .compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler())
} returns  Observable.just(true)
```

and then

```
every {
    remoteLocalInteractor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()
} returns  Observable.just(true)
```

`interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()` returns `ObservableJust`. All right

But `interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty().compose()` returns `NPE`, composer is null

[image: Case 1]

And when i write first

```
every {
    interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty().compose(...)
} returns Observable.just(true)
```

and then

```
every { 
    interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty() 
} returns Observable.just(true)
```

`interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty().compose()` returns `ObservableJust`. All right.

But `interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()` returns `Observable(child of #1#3)` and i need to have an `ObservableJust` Object

[image: Case 2]

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class RemoteLocalPresenterTest : BaseTest() {

  @Before
  override fun setup() {
      super.setup()
      remoteLocalInteractor = spyk()
      remoteLocalPresenter = RemoteLocalPresenter(
          remoteLocalInteractor,
          schedulerProvider,
          compositeDisposable,
          remoteLocalConfigConverter
      )
      remoteLocalPresenter.onAttach(remoteLocalView)
  }

  @Test
  fun 
  testShouldSaveDefaultConfigurations_serverConfigurationsIsEmpty_onSuccess(){
      every {
          remoteLocalInteractor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()
      } returns  Observable.just(true)

      every {
          remoteLocalInteractor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()
              .compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler())
      } returns  Observable.just(true)

      remoteLocalPresenter.shouldSaveDefaultConfigurations(activity)
  }
}
```

And this is my func to be tested

```
override fun shouldSaveDefaultConfigurations(activity: BaseActivity) {
        getView()?.showProgress()
        interactor?.let { interactor ->
            interactor.isServerConfigurationEmpty().concatMap { isEmpty ->
                if (isEmpty)
                    Observable.just(ClientTO())
                else
                    Observable.just(false)
            }.compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler())
                .subscribe({ res ->
                    when (res) {
                        is ClientTO -> {
                            getView()?.hideProgress()
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
                        }
                        else -> {
                            getView()?.let {
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, { err ->
                    CommonUtil.handleErrors(err)
                })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by mocking the result of my `schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler()`.

The main problem was to work with `Schedulers.io()` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. Then i found this amazing post on medium. [Fixing unit test issue of RxJava Chain and Kotlin](https://medium.com/@elye.project/fixing-unit-test-issue-of-rxjava-chain-and-kotlin-746fcef5ade8).

So before i need to make an observable call i do this.

```
every {
    schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler<Scheduler>()
} answers {
    ObservableTransformer { upstream -> 
        upstream.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
    }
}
```

So, now mi test looks like:

```
@Test
fun testShouldSaveDefaultConfigurations_serverConfigurationsIsEmpty_onSuccess() {
    every {
        schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler<Scheduler>()
    } answers {
        ObservableTransformer { upstream -> 
           upstream
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        }
    }

    every {
        remoteLocalInteractor.isServerConfigurationEmpty()
    } returns Observable.just(true)

    remoteLocalPresenter.shouldSaveDefaultConfigurations(activity)

    verify(remoteLocalPresenter.getView())?.hideProgress()
}
```

Hope this helps someone.